# Roots of $z^{2n} + \alpha z^{2n -1} + \beta ^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots, residue-calculus

I've been looking at a problem available [here](http://math.utsa.edu/~gokhman/ftp//courses/prob/cx_ucb.pdf). The problem is:

Let $n$ be a natural number, and $\alpha$, $\beta$ nonzero reals. Show that the number of roots of $p(z) = z^{2n} + \alpha z^{2n -1} + \beta ^2$ in the right half plane is
\begin{cases}
n&&\text{ if } n \text{ is even} \\
n \pm 1 &&\text{ if } n \text{ is odd} 
\end{cases}

I have a solution which uses the Argument Principle. The contour consists of two pieces: the line segment on the imaginary axis from $Ri$ to $-Ri$, and the semicircle in the right half-plane which connects $-Ri$ to $Ri$. Evaluating each piece separately and passing to the limit as $R \to \infty$ gives the answer (the $\pm 1$ for the odd case appears because of the branch cut for log$()$ on the negative real axis).

My question is this: Is there another way to do this which does not involve using the Argument Principle? I thought maybe you could use a conformal map from the open unit disk to the right half-plane in order to rewrite the problem in terms of zeros on the unit disk (and then use Rouche's Theorem), but I didn't succeed in getting it to work.

Thanks again!

Comment: I am also trying to solve that problem using the argument principle, but cannot find where the difference between odd and even cases is. I understand that the argument change on the semicircle is $2n\pi$, but it seems like the change is zero on the purely imaginary segment. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you be more specific about your solution? I'm also trying to solve this problem.And I think the solution by Daniel Fischer is too hard for me (like the Newton algorithm).So I wonder if there is another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For even $n$, we can directly use Rouché's theorem with the function $f(z) = z^{2n}+\beta^2$, using the half-disk with centre $0$ and radius $R$ in the right half plane. If $R$ is large enough, it contains all zeros of $p$ and of $f$ in the right half plane, and on the semicircle we have $\lvert f(z)-p(z)\rvert < \lvert f(z)\rvert$, while on the segment of the imaginary axis, $f(z)$ is real and strictly positive, but $f(z) - p(z) = \alpha z^{2n-1}$ is purely imaginary.

Thus $f(z) + \lambda (p(z)-f(z))$ has no zeros on the boundary of the half-disk for any $\lambda \in [0,1]$, and Rouché's theorem asserts that $p$ has equally many roots in the half disk as $f$. For $R > \lvert\beta\rvert^{1/n}$, exactly half of the roots of $f$ lie in the right half-plane, so we have $n$ roots for $p$ in the right half plane.

For odd $n$, we can't use quite the same argument, since then $z^{2n}+\beta^2$ has two simple roots on the imaginary axis (and $n-1$ roots in either half-plane).

But $h_\lambda(z) = f(z) + \lambda(p(z)-f(z))$ still has no zeros on the boundary of the half-disk for $\lambda \in (0,1]$, since $\alpha z^{2n-1}$ is purely imaginary on the imaginary axis, so the number of zeros of $h_\lambda$ in the right half plane is independent of $\lambda\in (0,1]$.

For $\lambda \to 0$, the zeros of $h_\lambda$ converge to the zeros of $f$, and the question is whether the two purely imaginary zeros $\zeta^{\pm} = \pm i\lvert\beta\rvert^{1/n}$ of $f$ are reached from the left or the right half plane.
The coefficients of $h_\lambda$ are real, hence the non-real roots occur in conjugate pairs, and therefore the two roots $\zeta^\pm$ are both reached from the same half-plane. If they are reached from the left half-plane, $p$ has $n-1$ roots in the right half-plane, and if they are reached from the right half-plane, $p$ has $n+1$ roots in the right half-plane.

For very small $\lambda > 0$, one step of the Newton algorithm leads to the approximation

$$\zeta^\pm_\lambda \approx \zeta^\pm - \frac{\lambda\alpha}{2n}\cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\lambda\alpha}{\zeta^\pm}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)}$$

of the zeros, which lies in the left half plane if $\alpha > 0$, and in the right if $\alpha < 0$.

Comment: OK cool - I like this argument, a lot. Is it correct that the idea behind using $\lambda$ is that the roots of the function parametrized by $\lambda$ depend continuously on $\lambda$ and so if there were a difference in the number of zeros, then one would have to cross the imaginary axix? I've not so far seen a version of Rouché's theorem quite like this, it's clear it should be true. Do you have a reference for me to look at? Thanks again. You always have great answers.

Comment: The proof of Rouché's theorem considers $$N_\lambda = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial V} \frac{f'(z) + \lambda(g'(z)-f'(z))}{f(z)+ \lambda (g(z)-f(z))}\,dz$$ which counts the zeros of $f + \lambda(g-f)$ in $V$. The conclusion is that $N_0 = N_1$, under the condition that no $f+\lambda(g-f)$ has a zero on $\partial V$. Often, in the statement of the theorem, that is guaranteed by the condition $\lvert g-f\rvert < \lvert f\rvert$ on $\partial V$, which is a simple _sufficient_ condition. The condition $\lvert g-f\rvert < \lvert f\rvert +\lvert g\rvert$ on $\partial V$ is an exact condition, but

Comment: somewhat less easy to understand. That's where the $\lambda$ originally comes from, the important thing is that _the integral_ that counts the zeros depends continuously on $\lambda$ (but, if you look deeper, that is of course because the zeros depend continuously on $\lambda$, that is a little bit problematic in case some $h_\lambda$ in between has a multiple zero, but in the right formulation, the zeros still depend continuously on $\lambda$, there are $N$ functions, ...). Here, the edge case that one of the functions had zeros on the boundary forced to look deeper. Luckily, the behaviour

Comment: is easy enough to handle, since there are only two (conjugat) zeros on the boundary, and we have a polynomial with real coefficients.

Comment: Amazing. Are you a mathematician by trade?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But by heart.

Comment: If you don't mind: Which, if any, complex analysis book did you learn from?

Comment: I first read Fischer/Lieb, Funktionentheorie. Excellent book, I still rate it as the best textbook I ever read. Later Rudin and Ahlfors, Forster's book on Riemann Surfaces (all three also excellent), and parts of several others (complete list lost in the mists of history). And several on Several Complex Variables; Grauert/Fritzsche, Hörmander, Range, Gunning/Rossi, parts of Kaup/Kaup and Krantz. But I've forgotten most of the SCV stuff, planning to re-read some of them.